# R XML xpathSApply encoding with latin character

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I have a problem with encoding in R program, this is my code.

```
library(XML) 
library(httr) 
doc <- xmlInternalTreeParse("http://interwp.cepal.org/sisgen/ws/cepalstat/getDimensions.asp?idIndicator=1246&language=spanish")
```

This works properly, and download the result in the appropriate encoding, however when I query "name", this is displayed with a wrong encoding, please help.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//dimensions/dim/@name")
```

This is the result

name

"PaÃ­s" 
"ClasificaciÃ³n econÃ³mica Operaciones del gobierno" 
....
"AÃ±os"

Tks

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the encoding of the result of `xpathSApply()` to "UTF-8".

`result <- xpathSApply(doc, "//dimensions/dim/@name") 
Encoding(result) <- "UTF-8" 
paste(result, collapse=" ")`.

Gives me: 
"País Clasificación económica Operaciones del gobierno Cobertura institucional Años".